# PHP code to check if game server is online

Tags: php, sockets, server

I'm trying to make a status-message on my website for a gaming server of mine. If it's online, it's supposed to say "online" and such.

This is the code I'm having at the moment:

```
<?php
$site = '217.78.24.5';
$port = '28728';
$check = fsockopen( "$site", "$port", $errno, $errstr, 6 );
if ( ! $check ){ echo 'Offline';
}
else{ echo 'Online (YAY)';}
?>
```

But it keeps telling me offline for some reason.
The game is CS:GO, if it matters

Comment: try `fsockopen($site, $port);` and don't forget to close socket

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be in $errno and $errstr, edit your code for:

```
$debug = true;
$site = '217.78.24.5';
$port = '28728';
$check = fsockopen( $site, $port, $errno, $errstr, 6 );
if ( ! $check ) {
   if($debug){
      echo "Error #$errno : $errstr <br>";
   } 
   echo 'Offline';     
}
else { 
   echo 'Online (YAY)';
}
```

If you see:

> Error #13 : Permission denied

It's maybe you firewall.

Comment: 'Error #110 : Connection timed out' is what I get :/

Comment: Last parameter of fsockopen. Try change 6 for 60 seconds.

Comment: Still the same error, but now it also takes a good long time for the page to load :P